# How do i access the text of the selected radio button in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, radio-button

I am creating a project for my new understanding of JavaFX GUI. I am just having trouble getting the file to write "Small Cake", "Medium Cake", or "Large Cake" depending on which radio button has been selected. I know most of my logic is working and it has come down to the

writer.write(cakeSize.getSelectedToggle().selectedProperty().getValue().toString());

No matter the documentation I look at or what . selector I choose I can only seem to access the Boolean stating if is it 'true' for selected or not and if not that then it returns the name value as 'selected'

It does not need to use setText(value) I can get rid of those setters if needed I was just trying to find where I went wrong. Without those it just returns in an object the "Small" "Medium" or "Large" based on selection. Those being written on their own to the file I am fine with as well.

Thanks!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;

public class BakeryApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        //Create a pane
        //the pane is the layout container that contains other JavaFX components
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        //Create a label and pass it through the pane layout
        Label orderTitle = new Label("Place your Cake Order Below");
        Label nameTitle = new Label("First and Last Name");
        Label numberTitle = new Label("Please enter your phone number:");
        //Create a text field area
        TextField name = new TextField();
        TextField number = new TextField();

        Label cakeSizeTtl = new Label("Please select your Cake Size:");
        RadioButton cakeSm = new RadioButton("Small");
        cakeSm.setText("Small Cake");
        RadioButton cakeMd = new RadioButton("Medium");
        cakeMd.setText("Medium Cake");
        RadioButton cakeLg = new RadioButton("Large");
        cakeLg.setText("Large Cake");

        ToggleGroup cakeSize = new ToggleGroup();
        cakeSm.setToggleGroup(cakeSize);
        cakeMd.setToggleGroup(cakeSize);
        cakeLg.setToggleGroup(cakeSize);




        Label cakeTypeTtl = new Label("Please select your Cake Type:");
        //Combo Box
        ComboBox<String> cakeSelection = new ComboBox<>();
        cakeSelection.getItems().addAll("Apple","Carrot", "Cheesecake","Chocolate", "Coffee", "Opera", "Tiramisu");
        cakeSelection.setValue("Cake Type");

        //create a save and quit button
        Button saveBtn = new Button("Save");
        Button quitBtn = new Button("Quit");

        //Events for buttons
        saveBtn.setOnAction(e -> {

                    try {
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("Order.txt"));
                        writer.write(number.getText());
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.write(name.getText());
                        writer.newLine();
                        //add cakeType selection
//                        writer.write(cakeSize.getSelectedToggle().selectedProperty().toString());
                        writer.write(cakeSize.getSelectedToggle().selectedProperty().getValue().toString());
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.write(cakeSelection.getValue());
                        //add cakeSize selection
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException err) {
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

        //handles click event on quit button to exit program
        quitBtn.setOnAction(e ->{
            Platform.exit();
        });
        //add an HBox to hold the buttons and arrange them horizontally
        HBox buttonBox = new HBox(10, saveBtn, quitBtn);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        //node, column, row
        gridPane.setConstraints(orderTitle,2,0);
        gridPane.setConstraints(nameTitle,2,1);
        gridPane.setConstraints(name, 2, 2);
        gridPane.setConstraints(numberTitle,2,3);
        gridPane.setConstraints(number, 2, 4);
        gridPane.setConstraints(cakeSizeTtl, 3, 5);
        gridPane.setConstraints(cakeSm, 3, 6);
        gridPane.setConstraints(cakeMd, 3, 7);
        gridPane.setConstraints(cakeLg, 3, 8);
        gridPane.setConstraints(cakeTypeTtl, 2, 5);
        gridPane.setConstraints(cakeSelection, 2, 6);
        gridPane.setConstraints(buttonBox, 3, 11);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        //use getChildren and add method to  place the label node in the pane layout
       gridPane.getChildren().addAll(buttonBox, orderTitle, name, number, nameTitle, numberTitle, cakeSm, cakeMd, cakeLg, cakeSizeTtl, cakeSelection, cakeTypeTtl);
        //Use BorderPane to aid in layout
        //controls are typically inserted into a different
        //type  of layout and then added into the BorderPane accordingly
        //like how our buttons and title are in a GridPane right now
        BorderPane mainPain = new BorderPane();
        mainPain.setCenter(gridPane);
        //add the pane to the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPain, 500, 500);
        stage.setTitle("Assignment2 Order Your Cake!");
        //Placing the Scene in the stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        //Displays the Stage
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //launches the Stage
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: please read the api doc of ToggleButton: selected != text (the former is of type boolean, the latter of type String), if you wan the text then .. ask for the text :) Also read the api doc of the constructor taking a String (it's a short-cut for instantiating plus calling setText - so your setting another text after that constructor doesn't make sense). And the getValue in the chained call (the first code line you are showing in the description) is the value of the _selectedProperty_ which always is either true or false)

Comment: I will look at the API doc again, I have already but like I said I am new to JavaFX so was looking for clarification. I really don't understand why people are so brutal on here. I even mentioned that I have been looking and trying to understand the documentation in my question. Everyone starts out new somewhere and I genuinely am trying to research as much as I can before asking a question.

Comment: I just went and reviewed it again along side what you have said and while what you have said confirms what I thought it was doing, as stated in my question, it does not answer how to get the small medium or large to be saved to the file upon selection. If you did try to answer that then please state where otherwise what I am looking for clarification on how to do, is still being left unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the `ToggleGroup` for the currently selected `Toggle` using the `getSelectedToggle()` or `selectedToggleProperty()` method, as you are already doing.

However `Toggle` is an interface that doesn't define a text property. The [`Toggle`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Toggle.html) interface has many implementations, one of which is `RadioButton`.
Now, since you know that your `ToggleGroup` only contains `RadioButton` toggles you can safely cast it and ask for its text.

Briefly:

```java
RadioButton selectedToggle = (RadioButton) cakeSize.getSelectedToggle();
if (selectedToggle != null) // it can be null if nothing is selected
   String selectedText = selectedToggle.getText();
```